# How can I implement custom .swipeActions() in my Scrollview-LazyVStack?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-swipeactions

I've tried all the available libraries out there but there are bugs which prevent me from scaling with these libraries.

- [SwipeActions](https://github.com/aheze/SwipeActions) (Triggers are not reliable, I'm able to reliably reproduce the unintended results - have filed an issue on their Git)
- [SwipeActions](https://github.com/c-villain/SwipeActions) (Swipe animation get stuck on Xcode 15/ iOS 17)
- [SwipeCells](https://github.com/fatbobman/SwipeCell) (Doesn't work well with buttons or NavigationLink())

Are there any good resources out there how I might implement swipeActions on LazyVStack cells?

```
struct CellView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView{
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Some other Views")) {
                            Text("Item #\(item)").padding()
                        }
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("SwipeActions")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to building custom SwiftUI views so appreciate your inputs! (: